# Outlook reminders not appearing

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007, reminder

I have tried using the steps provided in a [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286166) and they did not resolve it.
I tried:

```
outlook /cleanreminders
outlook /resetfolders
```

They did not fix it. The machine is running Outlook 2007 on Windows XP Pro. I have tried restarting the machine and I checked for processes running in the background. The outlook web access shows the reminders but they do not appear on the machine at hand. I have not tried getting the user to log into another machine to see if they work or not as she is away for a few hours.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like the profile may be corrupted?  can you copy their pst/ost to another location and rebuild the profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user came back I reinstalled the Office Suite, I made sure all the Windows updates were applied, rebooted the machine, and that fixed the issue. Not sure what was causing it but that fixed. There was probably an easier solution though. I did not try to rebuild the users profile.